# Multi-select Dropdown Data Not Displaying In Subpanel

Tags: sugarcrm, multi-select, suitecrm

In one of my modules say (Module1) I have a custom multi-select dropdown field. Module1 is in M:N relation with module2. The multi-select dropdown field data is displayed in the Edit, List & Detail views of module1 but it does not display in the subpanel for module1 under the module2 record.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you defined the subpanel to display the field and it's not showing up (indicating a software bug), or do you need instructions on adding the field to the subpanel?

Comment: I have added the field to display in the subpanel. but the field data is showing as blank.

Comment: In Sugar 7 there is a similar bug, but I don't see how SuiteCRM would have the same issue or workaround. But, on the off-chance that they're related, try adding the Multiselect field to the module's list view as well. Also ensure you've run a repair and rebuild. If neither fix the issue, you could try reporting this as a bug to the SuiteCRM community or diving in to find and repair the bug yourself, and ideally sharing your experience and resolution so SuiteCRM can include the fix with its next release.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for your reply. Yes I think its a bug in SuiteCRM also. I am trying for a workaround for my problem. Can u tell me how to parse html characters? In my custom field I am inserting data by appending an html "<br>" tag, but in detail view it is displayed as it is. I have tried using html field, but its a readonly field & can not edit data so its not useful. Waiting for your reply.